# 13.10: how to bring back one-click song open?

Tags: unity-dash, music

In the dash Music scope,
since the update, clicking on the song(not an album) displays a secondary menu
instead of playing the song.
How can I roll back to the good old behavior?

Comment: What is the secondary menu ?

Comment: Show in folder/play. And the zoomed in thumbnail. I see how that could make sense for an
album, but for a song...

Comment: Have you checked weather your file behaviour preferences been changed to double click from single click ?

Comment: The issue is with the secondary menu, not the single/double clicking. I want the secondary menu gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new dash behavior is double click to open and single click to preview
If you need to restore the previous behavior use `dconf editor`

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

open dconf editor in the dash and uncheck the com -> canonical -> unity -> double-click-activate

[image]